# Monthly total count of overall users in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I need the monthly new user count and the total count of users until that month end  in Oracle SQL. Can calculate monthly new users, but struggling to count total for that month.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS REGISTERED_USERS, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ADD_DATE) AS MN, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_DATE) AS YR 
FROM USERS 
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_DATE) = 2020
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ADD_DATE), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_DATE)
ORDER BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ADD_DATE);
```

Comment: I don't really see why you deleted your original question, only to post the exact same question again by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You want a running total. You get this with `SUM OVER`.

```
SELECT yr, mn, new_users, total_users
FROM
(
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM add_date) AS yr,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM add_date) AS mn,
    COUNT(*) AS new_users,
    SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM add_date), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM add_date)) AS total_users
  FROM users 
  GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM add_date), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM add_date)
)
WHERE yr = 2020
ORDER BY yr, mn;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SUM` analytical function with `COUNT` aggregate function and running the analytical function on `add_date` by `month` as follows:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DT) yr, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DT) mn, new_users, total_users
FROM
(
  SELECT
    TRUNC(ADD_DATE, 'MON') AS DT,
    COUNT(*) AS new_users,
    SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY TRUNC(ADD_DATE, 'MON')) AS total_users
  FROM users 
  GROUP BY TRUNC(ADD_DATE, 'MON')
)
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DT) = 2020
ORDER BY YR, MN;
```